# How to use $_GET with paginator?

Tags: php, get, zend-framework2, zend-paginator

I added in my project sorting data by select->order by $GET-variables. But when I navigate through the pages by paginator, of course this variables are not passing on the next page. What is the best way to pass this variables and use it with paginator?

Controller:

```
public function indexAction()
{
    $sortForm = new \Records\Form\SortingForm();
    $field = 'date';
    $order = 'desc';
    $request = $this->getRequest();

    if ($request->isGet()){
        $sortForm->setValidationGroup(array('field', 'order'));
        $sortData = $request->getQuery()->toArray();
        $sortForm->setData($sortData);

        if($sortForm->isValid()) {
            $sortForm->getData($sortData);
            $field = (string) $this->params()->fromQuery('field', 'date');
            $order = (string) $this->params()->fromQuery('order', 'desc');
        }
    }
    $query = $this->getRecordsTable()->fetchAll($field, $order);

    $paginator = new Paginator\Paginator(new Paginator\Adapter\Iterator($query));
    $paginator->setCurrentPageNumber($this->params()->fromRoute('page', 1));
    $paginator->setItemCountPerPage(25);

    $vm = new ViewModel(array('records' => $paginator));
```

Model:

```
public function fetchAll($field, $order)
    {
        $this->field = $field;
        $this->order = $order;
        $resultSet = $this->tableGateway->select(function (Select $select) {
        $select->columns(array('date', 'name', 'email', 'homepage', 'text', 'image', 'file'));
        $select->order($this->field.' '.$this->order);        
        });
        $resultSet->buffer();
        $resultSet->next();

        return $resultSet;
    }
```

Form:

```
public function __construct($name = null)
    {
        parent::__construct('records');
        $this->setAttribute('method', 'get');

        $this->add(array(
            'name' => 'field',
            'required' => false,
            'type'  => 'Zend\Form\Element\Select',
            'options' => array(
                'label' => 'Sort by: ',
                'value_options' => array(
                    'date' => 'Date', 
                    'email' => 'E-mail', 
                    'name' => 'Username',
            ),
        )));
        $this->add(array(
            'name' => 'order',
            'required' => false,
            'type'  => 'Zend\Form\Element\Select',
            'options' => array(
                'value_options' => array(
                    'asc' => 'ascending', 
                    'desc' => 'descending', 
            ),
        )));
        $this->add(array(
            'name' => 'submit',
            'attributes' => array(
                'type'  => 'submit',
                'value' => 'Go',
                'id' => 'submitbutton',
            ),
        ));
    }
```

Paginator view:

```
<!-- Numbered page links -->
<?php foreach ($this->pagesInRange as $page): ?>
  <?php if ($page != $this->current): ?>
    <a href="<?php echo $this->url($this->route, array('page' => $page)); ?>">
        <?php echo $page; ?>
    </a> |
  <?php else: ?>
    <?php echo $page; ?> |
  <?php endif; ?>
<?php endforeach; ?>
```

And another one: when I passing get-variables, the query string looks like http://guest-book.me/page/7?field=date&order=asc**&submit=Go** How I can do not send pair submit=>value?

Thank you for help! :)

Comment: And another one: omit submits 'name' element

Comment: try looking here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8852374/zend-paginator-make-other-links-and-action-calling-concatinating-with-the-url?rq=1

Comment: @Waygood thanks for answer. Zend\Form\Fieldset::add: element or fieldset provided is not named, and no name provided in flags - if omit 'name'. If about link - doesn't help...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Firstly, you need to make sure the route you're using for the Paginator has a Query String child route, I would recommend having a route specifically for use with listings with pagination, an example:

```
'router' => array(
    'routes' => array(
       'paginator_route' => array(
            'type' => 'segment',
            'options' => array(
                'route' => '/list/:controller/:action[/page/:page][/]',
                'constraints' => array(
                    //'__NAMESPACE__' => 'Application\Controller',
                    'controller'    => '[a-zA-Z][a-zA-Z0-9_-]*',
                    'page'          => '[0-9]+',
                ),
                'defaults' => array(
                    'controller' => 'index',
                    'action'     => 'list',
                    'page'       => 1,
                ),
            ),
            'may_terminate' => true, // with or without Query string
            'child_routes'  => array(
                'query' => array( // allows us to match query string
                    'type' => 'Query',
                    'options' => array(
                        'defaults' => array(
                            // Query string defaults here..
                        )
                    )
                ),
            ),
        ),
```

You now need to modify your pagination view to allow us to use current parameters as a base when generating the new links:

```
<!-- Numbered page links -->
<?php foreach ($this->pagesInRange as $page): ?>
  <?php if ($page != $this->current): ?>
    <?php // the last param allows us to reuse the matched params ?>
    <a href="<?php echo $this->url($this->route, array('page' => $page), TRUE); ?>">
        <?php echo $page; ?>
    </a> |
  <?php else: ?>
    <?php echo $page; ?> |
  <?php endif; ?>
<?php endforeach; ?>
```

Your pagination links should now retain the Query string values :-)

Comment: thanks, it works! But some questions: 1) my query string looks like /page/3/?field=date&order=asc&controller=Records\Controller\Records&action=index now when I passing on pages through paginator. But what if I want to hide 'controller' and 'action' variable from the url? My router: 'route'    => '[/page/:page][/]',                           'defaults' => array('controller' => 'Records\Controller\Records','action'   => 'index','page' => 1,), in "may terminate">>"Query">>"options":
'defaults' => array('field' => 'date','order' => 'desc').

Comment: and 2) is it possible to rewrite /page/3/?field=date&order=asc to /page/3/date/asc without mod_rewrite, but php/zf2? Thank you very much

Comment: you can't rewrite them like that because then they becaome part of the routes segments and no longer a query string, if you want them to be shown like that then just change your route to manage them.

Comment: thanks again. How I can change my route to manage them like /.../?

Comment: and about my first question - can I "hide" some variables from dislpaying in url?

Comment: you can't hide anything you want to be passed during a GET request, what are you trying to do, why do you need it hidden?

Comment: actually, I need an url that looks like /page/:page/:field/:order , where page = number of page field = date|url|name etc (fields in db by which I am sorting data) and order = asc|desc. I made sorting by the Zend/Form, from form data sends by $_GET. I want to rewrite ?field=smth&order=smth by mod_rewrite, but if it possible to make with ZF2 tools, I want so.

Comment: and another one: is it possible to pass some variables to paginator control? Thank you for help

Comment: checkout the paginator control paramters: $this->paginationControl($items, 'Sliding', 'pagination/default.phtml' /*, $this->paginationParams*/)

Answer (score 0):

you can create a helper that pass a GET parameter to url too. i've created a sample module for this : https://github.com/samsonasik/SanSamplePagination

Comment: thanks, your blog helped me ones yet - maybe you helped me one more time:)